# Error VUE $data

Tags: vue.js

tengo 2 problemas uno es que si en mi VUE elimino esto que lo estaba utilizando como testing, me deja de funcionar la aplicación, a que se puede deber esto?? Y que tendría que hacer para poder sacarlo?

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
                <h1>JSON</h1>
                <pre>
                    {{ $data | json }}
                </pre>
            </div>
```

Y digamos si yo le pongo un v-show como sentencia para que no se muestre, no me lo muestra pero como que me coloca un footer azul el cual no puedo sacar por ningun lado, no se si esto tendrá que ver con el $data json pero yo creo que pueden estar relacionados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Definición de la APP:

```
var vue = new Vue({
    el: "#vue", 
    components: {
    draggable: window['vuedraggable']
  },
    //router,
    data: {
        json: false,
        status: 0,
        timerCount: 0,
        datos:{
            user:'',
            pass:'',
            ultimaPregunta: false,
            estado: false,
            endExam: false,
            opcionesSelecMultiple:[],
            respondio:'',
            preguntaAcutal:[],
            seleccion3:'', 
            seleccion2: 
                {
                    valor0:'',
                    valor1:'',
                    valor2:'',
                    valor3:'',
                    valor4:''

                },
            seleccion:'', 
            idexam:'',
            jwt: '',
            status:'',
            respuesta:{
                estado:'',
                resp:'',
                check: true
            }, 
            datosExamen:[],
            opcionesQuestion:[
               {
                   option_id:'',
                   question_id:'',
                   text:[{}],
                   options:[{}]
                }
            ],
            dataFinal:''
            
           

        },
        
    }
```

Todo el código HTML realizado desde la sentencia inicial hasta la final:

```
DELETED
```

Error:

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: json

(found in <Anonymous>)
```

Comment: Hay dos preguntas en 1 (trata de hacer las preguntas de a una).. y luego, falta informacion en cada una de ellas. Sacas eso, y que queda? hay error en la consola? y la otra, como esta definida la app???

Comment: Es que creo yo que son por el mismo motivo que ocurren, estoy bastante seguro. No me aparece ningún error en consola y como esta definida a que te referís? Estoy utilizando CDN si es eso a lo que te referís.

Comment: No no. Necesitamos ver como esta armado tu vue para saber que esta pasando... asi como esta solo podemos suponer escenarios...

Comment: @gbianchi Ahí edite la pregunta original con la definición de la app, prometo que después de este proyecto comienzo a trabajar con vue cli

Comment: Claro pero tu problema es el (digamos) html.. el codigo vue no aporta nada a este problema...

Comment: @gbianchi Bueno perfecto ahí lo subí, mira que es muchisimo codigo, no lo iba a subir porque se que esta mal hacerlo así pero bueno es como me salio todavía estoy aprendiendo, pero si no querés ayudarme después de verlo lo entiendo perfectamente.

Comment: Ahora que me fijo si me esta tirando un error, ahí te lo dejo comentado también en la pregunta.

Comment: ok, si, va a ser imposible darse cuenta con ese codigo. Lo que te recomiendo es que uses componentes, que para eso esta vue. Cada uno de tus v-if segun el tipo de cosa a mostrar, deberia ser un componente, entonces el codigo te queda compartimentado y vas a encontrar el problema mucho mas facil. Y si usas CDN, pasarlo a vue cli es una pavada, el cli ya te genera la estructura directamente, solo vas a tener que copiar este codigo alli

Comment: @gbianchi si lo se, es que todavía me cuesta trabajar con componentes y Vuex más que nada, pero mil gracias igualmente por todo!

Comment: y aca tu solucion: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/data-json-is-not-valid-in-2-0/451

Comment: Vuex no tiene nada que ver con componentes.. y un componente es solo un poco de vue con html.. es como tener muchas paginas contenidas en una... y tu error salio en una busqueda en google ;)

Comment: @gbianchi Si ahí se me soluciono el error ese, muchas gracias. Puede que este equivocado, se que no tiene nada que ver con componentes pero lo que había entendido es que el flujo de datos mayormente se utilizaba con Vuex, pero bueno voy a tratar de pasarlo a CLI como vos me decís con componentes y vue simplemente. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda de siempre!

Comment: Vuex ayuda como un repositorio de datos, pero no es obligatorio para nada.. se puede hacer todo sin vuex y despues aprender a usarlo.. facilita, si, es obligatorio, no....